# Connect to Samsung TV using AllShare from a Non-Samsung phone

Tags: nexus-5, smart-tv

I have a Nexus 5 phone and want to connect to my Samsung Smart TV (which supports AllShare). 
How can I do this?

Thanks.

UPDATE: I tried again after updating my phone to Android 5.0 . but no luck to getting this work .

Comment: "connect to": What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: There is a feature in Samsung Smart TV to connect your Samsung devices/phones to this TV through AllShare feature. I wanted to check whether this is possible through any NON-Samsung android phones. 
You can cast your mobile screen and content to your TV if it supports AllShare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and then I found an app called [Mirror](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.mirror) it allows you to mirror your android device screen to pretty much any streaming box or stick or smart TV with streaming capabilities like Samsung Smart TV's. You can even mirror to an Apple TV. With Mirror there is a bit of a delay from you doing something on your phone to it on the TV.

There is also an app called [AllCast](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.cast) for just streaming media like music, videos and movies that are on your phone or on one of the few media streaming websites that are available to stream within the app. These include: Twitch, Google+, Dropbox and Google Drive.

Comment: I've found AllCast to work as explained above. Not yet tried Mirror. Will try this and inform.

Answer (score 2):

This certainly solves the problem!

Go into your settings, go into WiFi, tap on the three dots in a vertical line to bring up the menu, select Advanced, then select Wi-Fi Frequency Band, once in there set it to 2.4GHz Only.

Then try your casting, if that doesn't work try setting it to 5GHz only.

Answer (score 0):

turn on allshare on the TV,
on the nexus go to settings / display / cast screen. 
it will start searching for a display over the wifi network. 
if both tv and phone are on the same wifi, the tv will show up. 
select the tv from list,  it will mirror the nexus screen.

Comment: I tried this, BUT on my LG Nexus 5 phone the TV was shown and when i touched it for connection it just shows "Connecting..." for some time and then disappears. On TV, the Media was turned ON in AllShare Settings. But my phone was not detected at all.

Comment: i have done this a couple of times with a samsung tv and my N5, it works. Are both on the same wifi network?

Comment: **Yes**, both are on the same Network, But my version of the Samsung TV does not have WiFi support, it supports Wired LAN which is connect to my WiFi router to which my N5 is connected.

Comment: Are both devices on the same subnet? perhaps the tv is on 192.168.0.1 and the phone on something else like 192.168.1.1

Comment: Yes both are on the same subnet and same the IP would be like 192.168.0.2 (mobile) 192.168.0.3 (TV)

Answer (score -2):

After you press cast screen, press 3 buttons in the upper right corner and check enable screen